# How to create a method that exchanges the location of two class variables?

Tags: java, variables

I'm trying to create a method that can exchange the location/reference of two class variables, but I can't change the reference of the class variable that is calling the method (`this`), so I'm wondering is there any way to get around this.

```
public void exchange(Card x) {
    Card y = this;
    this = x;  //this doesn't work
    x = y;

}
```

Comment: Java is always pass-by-value, so I doubt there is a way...

Comment: Why would that be needed?

Comment: You can't change the reference, but you _could_ swap the contents...   However it would probably be poor design.

Comment: It is possible if you have all cards in an array or something similar and pass the array and the references or indices which should be swapped.

Comment: You can't change `this`. Your `exchange` method seems to appear in a class `Card` since `Card y = this;` is legal. From a design standpoint, a Card shouldn't be swapping itself with another Card -- something outside that _contains_ Cards should do the swap. Maybe you have a `Game` that is maintaining 4 `Hand`s which each have 9 `Card`s, and there is a `Deck` of remaining Cards. What class would handle swapping a Card in one Hand with a Card from the Deck?

Comment: @StephenP that's the poor design I was alluding to in my comment

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't pass method arguments by reference; it passes them **by value**.

The method will fail since **Java passes object references by value** as well.

You can read more [here](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2077424/learn-java/does-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value.html).